# How do I make my react app fetch my proxy API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

my api call isn't sending to the proxy url domain. I know that it isn't calling as the console.log in the server isn't going off. Could someone please help me?

```js
//client package.json
"proxy":"http://localhost:3001"
```

```js
//client app

useEffect(() => {
    const apicall = async () => {
      try{
        const response = await fetch("/")

        if (response.status !== 200){
          throw new Error()
        }
        else{
          console.log("api call was success")
          console.log(response)
        }

    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }}
    apicall()
  }, [])
```

```js
//server
app.get("*", (req,res)=>{
    console.log("apicalled")
    res.cookie("refreshToken", 987654321, {
        maxAge: 60000,
        httpOnly: true
    })
    res.send("has cookie sent?")
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an answer for you, but it looks like you're using create-react-app? I think if you've setup your own server, you don't need to set the proxy in your `package.json`.

I am running a small react app and trying to access an external api behind my company's proxies. I continue to get the cors error - I've tried setting a proxy in package.json and using `setupProxy.js` (separately), but haven't had any luck.